# Can stylecop for jetbrains be run in visual studio 2017

Tags: development-environment, visual-studio-2017, stylecop

We used to write our code in visual studio 2013 with stylecop as a seperate plugin. When we wanted to check our code qualtiy we pressed ctrl+shift+y to run stylecop and get a log of infractions (if any)

Recently we switched to visual studio 2017 with resharper and integrated stylecop by JetBrains. While stylecop is still running (blue lines underneath infractions) we can't seem to get a complete log with all our errors (and when building a solution stylecop isn't automatically run).

I tried looking in tools -> Options -> environment -> Keyboard -> Show commands containing "Stylecop" (you used to find lots of settings in VS2013, none in 2017)

1. Is it still possible to run stylecop like we did in VS2013?
2. Is it possible to have stylecop run after a build is completed (in a post build event)?

Answer (score 1):

In Vsiual Studio 2017, the easiest way to enable and integrate StyleCop is to [enable the StyleCop Roslyn package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers/1.0.0). That way the Roslyn compiler will automatically run StyleCop live in the editor as well as during build.

Resharper should play nice with this as well and sync its settings to the stylecop settings.

Comment: I love that it runs Stylecop after the build. Thanks for that suggestion!


Although it doesn't seem to listen to the settings we made in Resharper -> Options -> Code Inspection - Inspection severity.


We have made some custom settings (like disable SA1500 Braces for multi-line statements must not share line) but now I get an error on build for that. Did I not configure my Stylecop in the right way? Do I need to do something to get the settings synced?

Comment: You need to check the current rules et for the project. Roslyn uses a slightly different way to configure these items.